# If this is a function that can tell if the selected element is present in parent element of the clicked element. I need help debugging this

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors, google-tag-manager, getelementbyid

I am making this variable for Google Tag Manager. The `{{Click Element}}` returns the element lets say "ul". I want to find the parent element with `"li"` and in the element, I want to search if `div.icon-lock` is descendant. The current code is not returning the correct result. Can anyone point out the mistake or suggest a better way?

```
function(){ 
  
  
var ul = {{Click Element}};
var el =( $("ul").closest("li"))

  
if ( $("el div").hasClass("icon-lock") ) { 

   return true
  }
 else {
 
  return false

}   

}
```

One of the HTML code I am using my function

```
<li _ngcontent-bvv-c8="" tabindex="0" id="5f2abd67d480440d11d7cec1">
  <div _ngcontent-bvv-c8="" class="cie-accordion-heading">
  <!---->
    <span _ngcontent-bvv-c8="" class="badge-red mr-3">Live Class
    </span>
<!---->Class on Series &amp; Patterns - 1
  </div>
  <div _ngcontent-bvv-c8="" class="cie-accordion-item flex-post">
  <!---->
    <div _ngcontent-bvv-c8="" class="flex-post-pic">
    <!---->
    <img _ngcontent-bvv-c8="" alt="video-img" src="angular/assets/img/course-experience/course-video.svg">
    <!---->
    <!---->
    <!---->
    <!---->
    </div>
 <div _ngcontent-bvv-c8="" class="flex-post-content text-light-sm text-truncate">
 <!---->
 <!---->
 <!---->
  <span _ngcontent-bvv-c8="">81 mins
  </span>
 <!---->
 <!---->
  <span _ngcontent-bvv-c8="" class="px-3">|
  </span>
  <span _ngcontent-bvv-c8="" class="text-light-sm">Was live on Aug 21
  </span>
 </div>
<!---->
 <div _ngcontent-bvv-c8="" class="icon-lock">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please provide the html

Comment: Unless the ul is nested inside an li, this logic is incorrectly using `closest()`, which only goes up the DOM.

Comment: `el` (as a string) is not a valid element. You might want something like `if (el.find('div.icon-lock').length)` instead.

Comment: @EugenSunic check the HTML code assigned. Every click will correspond to one of <li> </li> element and the nested code is similar for every case. Apologies if the code isn't indented properly. I want the descendant in <li> to have div.icon-lock and return true else false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for the the class by getting the the main div wrapper and then search for the descendant class.

```js
function hasIconLockClass() {
  const iconLock = document.querySelector('ul li div .icon-lock');
  if (!iconLock) return false
  return true
}

console.log(hasIconLockClass())
```

```html
<ul>


  <li _ngcontent-bvv-c8="" tabindex="0" id="5f2abd67d480440d11d7cec1">
    <div _ngcontent-bvv-c8="" class="cie-accordion-heading">
      <!---->
      <span _ngcontent-bvv-c8="" class="badge-red mr-3">Live Class
      </span>
      <!---->Class on Series &amp; Patterns - 1
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-bvv-c8="" class="cie-accordion-item flex-post">
      <!---->
      <div _ngcontent-bvv-c8="" class="flex-post-pic">
        <!---->
        <img _ngcontent-bvv-c8="" alt="video-img" src="angular/assets/img/course-experience/course-video.svg">
        <!---->
        <!---->
        <!---->
        <!---->
      </div>
      <div _ngcontent-bvv-c8="" class="flex-post-content text-light-sm text-truncate">
        <!---->
        <!---->
        <!---->
        <span _ngcontent-bvv-c8="">81 mins
        </span>
        <!---->
        <!---->
        <span _ngcontent-bvv-c8="" class="px-3">|
        </span>
        <span _ngcontent-bvv-c8="" class="text-light-sm">Was live on Aug 21
        </span>
      </div>
      <!---->
      <div _ngcontent-bvv-c8="" class="icon-lock">
      </div>
    </div>

  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: I don't want the first element but the function that can return true if the element div.icon-lock is present. I am creating a variable for google tag manager against every click. If click element is in closed list <li> ... </li> I want to check if div.icon-lock is present in the same list.

Comment: @swapnilindahood check the answer again

Comment: if the clicked element is "div.flex-post-pic", then the document.querySelector needs to defined ul as parent list, right?